# Python tokenizing strings

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I'm new to python and would like to know how I can tokenize strings based on a specified delimiter. 
For example, if I have the string "brother's" and I would like to turn it to ["brother", "\s"] or a string "red/blue" to ["red", "blue"], what would be the most appropriate way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I would start with `pydoc str` and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
>>> 'red/blue'.split('/')
['red', 'blue']
>>> "brother's".split("'")
['brother', 's']
```

Comment: Thanks. How about if I had something like "brothers'" with the single quote after "brothers" and I want it to be ['brother', '\'s']?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and it's called on the `str` object. For instance:

```
>>> brotherstring = "brother's"
>>> brotherstring.split("'")
['brother', 's']
>>> redbluestring = "red/blue"
>>> redbluestring.split("/")
['red', 'blue']
```

There are a few variants on `split`, such as `rsplit`, `partition`, etc that all do different things. Read the documentation to find the one that works best for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
>>> strr =  "brother's"
>>> strr.replace("'","\\'").split("\\")
['brother', "'s"]

>>> strrr = "red/blue"
>>> strrr.split('/')
['red', 'blue']
```

Comment: This is a great answer. It shows how to preserve punctuation, in the case that your punctuation is not your delimiter. Can reconstruct the original later, or clean further if the apostrophe is really unwanted.

Comment: @VISQL Thanks for the appreciation.